# How to get XML from a BLOB field in Oracle Database 11g?

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g, blob

This is the scenario, in a Oracle Database 11g, theres a BLOB field which has XML data which I need to query. I don't know how the XML was inserted into the blob field, but this is what I'm getting with a query using the DBMS_LOB.substr() function:

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like XML.

Comment: @Sentinel Could be after some encoding with convert() function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you do it:

- 1.
  First you have to find out structure of XML that was inserted into BLOB. For example:
  `select XMLTYPE(blob_field, 1) as XML from my_table;`
- 2.
  Now if you want to use substr function to extract specific string you can do the following:
  `SELECT substr(XMLTYPE (UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2 (blob_field)).EXTRACT('xml_tag/xml_tag/../text()'),200,200) as "XML DATA" FROM my_table where pk = 123123;`

In this example `xml_tag/xml_tag/../text()` is your xml structure. For example is my structure is `<Profile><Name>Your Customer Name</Name></Profile>`. So I will have to write as `Profile/Name/text()`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that the field does not have xml, maybe some binary data. I ended using a web service to get the info.